# Run next job in sequence even if the previous job fails in a Jenkins Build flow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-build-flow

I  have a build flow which builds 4 jobs in sequence

eg;

```
build(Job 1)
build(Job 2)
build(Job 3)
build(Job 4)
```

I want to run Job 4 even if any of the previous job fails also . How can I do that in the build flow  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set propagate to false, that will ensure your workflow will continue if particular job fails:

```
build job: '<job_name>', propagate: false
```

Comment: simplest answer and implementation :-)

Answer (score 1):

For me, `propagate: false` didn't worked, So I used `ignore(FAILURE)` instead in my BuildFlow, to make sure that all the jobs in flow executes, even if there are failures. ([Ref](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin))

```
  ignore(FAILURE) {
        build("JobToCall",  Param1: "param1Val", Param2: "param2Val")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenkins Workflow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) as follows:

```
try {
  build 'A'
} catch(e) {
  echo 'Build for job A failed'
}
try {
  build 'B'
} catch(e) {
  echo 'Build for job B failed'
}
```

You can extend this idiom to any number of jobs or any combination of success/failure flow you want (for example, adding `build` steps inside `catch`es if you want to build some job in case another failed).